# Перерисовка ListView

Tags: android-sdk, android-fragment, android

Добрый день форумчане! 
Ситуация вот какая. Есть Activity унаследованный от FragmentActivity  в котором создается TabHost с 3 вкладками (Две из которых ListFragment а третья вкладка простой Fragment). Так же есть customAdapter, отвечающий за нужную мне прорисовку. Все отображается замечательно, но при скролинге не перерисовывается. Может кто встречался с подобной ситуацией*? Прошу направить меня в правильное русло.

Код ListFragment:

```
public class PBAllContactsFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         ArrayList<String> allContacts = getAllContactsList();

        PBListAdapter listAdapter = new PBListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.all_listview_item_row, allContacts);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
 }
```

Код Adapter:

```
public class PBListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mLayoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<String> mContactsList = null;

    public PBListAdapter(Context pContext, int pLayoutResourceId, ArrayList<String> pList) {
        super(pContext, pLayoutResourceId, pList);
        this.mContext = pContext;
        this.mLayoutResourceId = pLayoutResourceId;
        this.mContactsList = pList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listRow = convertView;

        ContactsListHolder holder = null;

        if(listRow == null){

            Activity currentActivity = (Activity)mContext;
            LayoutInflater inflater = currentActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            listRow = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ContactsListHolder();

            holder.contact_photo = (ImageView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
            holder.star = (ImageView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.star);
            holder.contactName = (TextView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            holder.deleteButton = (Button) listRow.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
            holder.ordinalNumber = (TextView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.ordinal_number);

            holder.contactName.setText(mContactsList.get(position));
            holder.ordinalNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));

            listRow.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ContactsListHolder) listRow.getTag();
        }

        return listRow;

    }

    static class ContactsListHolder {

        ImageView contact_photo;
        ImageView star;
        TextView contactName;
        Button deleteButton;
        TextView ordinalNumber;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код выполняет то, что Вы ему поручили. Собственно "обновление" выполняется в else ветке метода getView. Думаю, метод нужно переписать хотя бы так

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    View listRow = convertView;

    ContactsListHolder holder = null;

    if(listRow == null){

        Activity currentActivity = (Activity)mContext;
        LayoutInflater inflater = currentActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        listRow = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ContactsListHolder();

        holder.contact_photo = (ImageView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.contact_photo);
        holder.star = (ImageView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.star);
        holder.contactName = (TextView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) listRow.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        holder.ordinalNumber = (TextView) listRow.findViewById(R.id.ordinal_number);

        listRow.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ContactsListHolder) listRow.getTag();

    }

    holder.contactName.setText(mContactsList.get(position));
    holder.ordinalNumber.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    return listRow;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Работает прекрасно)